Probability distribution of exponential chickens
This problem originates from minecraft chickens.

Let's say I start with one ( fully grown ) chicken.
This chicken lays one egg every $\left[5, 10\right]$ minutes, randomly.
It always lays an egg in this interval, and the probability of the chicken laying an egg at any time during the interval is constant.
This egg has a $1/8$ chance of turning into $1$ baby chicken, and a $1/256$ chance of turning into $4$ baby chickens.
Otherwise, in the $1 - \left(1/8 + 1/256\right) = 223/256$ case, nothing happens and the egg gets destroyed.
After laying an egg, they will again lay an egg in the next $5\mbox{-}10$ minutes.
This process repeats forever.
Furthermore, these baby chickens take $20$ minutes to grow up.
When they grow up, they are identical to a new adult chicken, laying an egg in $5\mbox{-}10$ minutes.
I wanted to make a function $\operatorname{f}\left(t,x\right)$ that tells me "At time $t$, what is the probability that you have $x$ or greater chickens ?".
I don't know how to take into account the "cooldown period," the time from $0\mbox{-}5$ minutes where a chicken has just laid an egg, or the "growing period," the time where a baby chicken is growing up.
The chickens never die.

How do I tackle this problem ?.

There's not enough information.  By "every 5-10 minutes, randomly" do you mean that the time to lay is uniformly distributed between $5$ and $10$ minutes?  Moreover, what happens during the $1 - 1/8 - 1/256 = 223/256$ chance where the egg neither turns into $1$ or $4$ baby chickens?  Also, do the chickens die?  Is an adult chicken fertile the moment it turns into an adult?  Does it always lay a new egg between $5$ and $10$ minutes after it has laid the last egg?

Sorry for lack of clarification, I will update the post

I don't know anything about this but the keyword you want is "branching process": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branching_process

To be faithful to the Minecraft origin, we could note that the game ticks 20 times per second. In that case we can simulate the hatching mechanic as follows: Five minutes after a chicken hatches or lays an egg, pick a random number from 1 to 20605=6000. After that many game ticks have elapsed, lay a new egg. The aging mechanic can be similarly simulated.
